# How do I number headings with the 'Heading 3' style in Word without affecting the other heading styles?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, styles, numbering, microsoft-word-2013

I would like my document to have the basic heading styling for Heading 1 and Heading 2 but for Heading 3 to be numbered. I can get close by defining my own modified multilevel list style but it introduces a tab at the start of each Heading 1 that I cannot remove and also numbers the Heading 3s as if the super-headings had been numbered (e.g. 1.1.2).

[image: Modifying multilevel list style]

How do I set up the style of a Word 2013 document so that Heading 3 is numbered but Heading 1 and Heading 2 are left untouched?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem but are you sure your Heading 3 style isn't based on either of the other heading styles?

Comment: Thanks Adam; how would I check that?

Comment: Right click on Heading 3 in the Quick Style panel and choose Modify. Is there anything showing under the "Style based on" combobox?